# Vertical stacking on bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically stack items on a bootstrap grid, but they're not stacking up correctly. Instead, it adds 4-5 items together to one row and breaks for next row. Is there anything bootstrap-native that can fix this? Or do I need some other workaround?

```
<div id="result-container" class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-3" style="height:220px">Item</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3" style="height:320px">Item</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3" style="height:270px">Item</div>
    ...
</div>
```

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgp2gqc6/).

[image: Current, wanted]

Comment: Blockquotes are designed for... well... blockquotes. Not to decorate JSFiddle links. I've edited that out.

Comment: Something like that? [Bootstrap + Isotope](http://mpezzi.github.io/bootstrap_isotope/)

Comment: Use isotope or masonry.. bootstrap grid is not meant for that.

Comment: You're looking for something called masonry. There is plenty to find about this topic, for example: http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

Comment: Use one row with each vertical stack in one column (i.e col-xs-4 with three items inside).

Comment: @Aibrean Thanks, that helped. Make it an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I've seen blockquotes to highlight content a couple of times around here - that's why I used it. But thanks for editing and for the note.

Comment: @MathijsRutgers, IndieRok Yeah, something like that. But I'd rather not implement another framework for that purpose.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I can't because they closed it.